# Unable to link docker containers from CLI

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I am trying to link two docker containers (WordPress and mysql) by using the command line but it did not work.I have also tried with docker-compose.yml but only one container is working and I am unable to link both containers.I have used following commands.I am currently using AWS Amazon Linux AMI.

```
docker run --name db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc123 -p 3306:3306 -d mysql
docker run --name wordpress  --link db:mysql -p 80:80 -d wordpress.
```

After running these commands only one container (MYSQL) is active:

[image: see image here]

Comment: Can you do execute `docker logs CONTAINERID` to see what the logs are? this might give you a hint on the error

Comment: I would assume your `wordpress` container crashes, so worth to look into its logs by looking up the original container id with `docker ps --all` to see previous ones too and then `docker logs <id>`

Comment: both image are mysql in the screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

That's easily manageable if you setup a `docker-compose.yml` having both containers within the same [network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network-configuration-reference):

```
version: '3'
services:
  # Containers
  my_wp_container:
    # ...
    # Container config goes here
    # ...
    networks:
      # Make sure both containers are in the same network
      - my_network_name
    links:
      # "Linking" containers makes it easy to refer to one container from another
      - my_mysql_container

  my_mysql_container:
    # ...
    # Container config goes here
    # ...
    container_name: my_mysql_container
    networks:
      - my_network_name

networks:
  # No additional configuration is required for the network other than
  # creating it; You are of course free to customize it to your needs
  my_network_name:
```

Running `docker-compose up` will spin up both containers simultaneously. Your WordPress container (`my_wp_container`) can reach MySQL easily as `my_mysql_container` is now a host alias know to WP's container.

Once both containers are running, try SSH'ing into `my_wp_container` and running:

```
ping my_mysql_container
```

You should see that one container can reach the other within it's docker network!

Comment: i am able to ping MySQL container but  while installing i am getting   same issue database hase not yet connected

Comment: @RakeshSivagouni Have you [enabled remote connections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779244) to MySQL? By default ot only accepts connections from the same host, and each container act as a different one.